# Python paramiko logging messes up stfp connection

Tags: python, paramiko

I am using paramiko to open a sftp connection to access a remote file. All my code below in a built in function seems to work only if I don't have the logging enabled for paramiko:

```
      paramiko.util.log_to_file( 'paramiko.log' )
```

So when I do NOT have the above line of code in my file the code below works:

```
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.load_system_host_keys()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy( paramiko.AutoAddPolicy() )
        client.connect( hostname,user, password)
        sftp = client.open_sftp()
        file = sftp.open( fpath, mode='r', bufsize=1 )
```

Otherwise python will hang on this line **client.connect( hostname,user, password)** and writes to the stderr log like crazy eventually killing the VM my code is running on.

Specifically paramiko hangs on this line:

```
t.start_client()
```

within the client.connect method. Nothing useful comes out in the paramiko log and stderr is filled with errors with no description or tracebacks.

Researching this problem I came across "There is a single import lock available so when a child thread attempts another import it can block it indefinitely" how do I make sure the code opening a sftp connection is never blocked?

Comment: For a start your're referencing `self._client` when it's not instantiated in your script. What is your actual code? There can be a literal infinity of reasons why Paramiko hangs. You're connecting by password and you haven't explicitly specified `look_for_keys`, which means it's set to True. This can cause authentication problems in `AuthHandler()`. Try adding `look_for_keys=False` to `client.connect()`.

Comment: Also, if think you're mistaken in what `log_to_file` does. If you look at the [actual code](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/paramiko/util.py), it outputs the steps that are happening. If an exception was raised it would be raised.

Comment: tried yout suggestion- look_for_keys does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a long shot, but I have had issues with `logging`'s use of threads causing deadlock.  I was not able to track the exact problem down (though I suspect it may have been exacerbated by the use of `subprocess`; but I did solve it by disabling the `logging` module's thread support.

Try this before you activate logging:

```
import logging
logging.thread = None
```

I'd be interested to know if this solves your problem or not.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately this did not work for me.