# Python Streamhandler over ftp doesn't work after second import

Tags: python, logging, ftp, paramiko

I have the following problem:

I wrote a FTPHandler(StreamHandler), which connects via 'transport=paramiko.Transport(...)' and 'transport.connect(...)' to a server and opens a sftp connection with 'SFTPClient.from_transport(...)'.

I am importing this handler in a class named 'JUS_Logger.py', which is my module for logging. This 'FMP_Logger' is imported by another class, 'JUS_Reader'.

The problem is, that if I start 'JUS_Reader', the transport is being initialized, but the Connection fails. There is no exception, the program only hangs. If I kill it, I get the stacktrace

```
CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./JUS_Reader.py", line 24, in <module>
    from JUS_Logger import logger
  File "/<home>/.../JUS_Logger.py", line 74, in <module>
    ftpHandler=FTPHandler(ftpOut,10)
  File "/<home>/FTPHandler.py", line 21, in __init__
        self.transport.connect(username=ftpOut['user'].decode('base64'),password=ftpOut['passwd'].decode('base64'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1004, in connect
    self.auth_password(username, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1165, in auth_password
    return self.auth_handler.wait_for_response(my_event)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/auth_handler.py", line 158, in wait_for_response
    event.wait(0.1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 403, in wait
    self.__cond.wait(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 262, in wait
    _sleep(delay)
```

However, if I'm running the 'JUS_Logger.py' by itself, everything works, the transport's connection establishes and the SFTClient connects also.

Any ideas? Or further questions?

Comment: Meanwhile, I found another post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119616/python-paramiko-logging-messes-up-stfp-connection) in which there's quite a similar problem. Turning off logging's thread however didn't solve the problem. Still deadlocking.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. Like stated [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119616/python-paramiko-logging-messes-up-stfp-connection), while importing, python keeps a lock, which paramiko tries to take while connecting. This leads to the deadlock. My solution is creating the transport in the FTPHandler.py and connecting in 'JUS_Reader's __init__.